# `return None` in python not recommended. How to bypass?

Tags: python, return-value, handle

I have a function which connects to a url by `httplib` using `lxml`. It checks by `xpath`for a certain pattern and if the check is positive it returns a string. But if the check was negative it returns nothing.

Now the situation is, that my function returns `None`. I call the function, check if its return value is `not None` and continue in the code.

An example:

```
def foobar(arg):
    # connect to page by httplib
    # check for arg in a certain pattern by lxml
    if check:
        return result
    else:
        return None

result = foobar(arg)
if result:
    # do stuff
else:
    # do other stuff
```

Recently I read, that this is a *no go*. How do I avoid such situations?

Comment: Just remove else: return None part?

Comment: You should propably use `if result is None` though.

Comment: What is the difference between `if result` and `if result is None`?

Comment: Using `if result is not None` instead of `if result` (note the `not`) means that other boolean false values such as `0` or `""` won't be treated the same as `None`, which is probably what you want. And if you want to be explicit in returning `None` (and there's nothing wrong with that) then an alternative for your foobar would be `return result if check else None`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with returning `None`.

In most cases, you don't need to explicitly return `None`. Python will do it for you. This is an altered version of your `foobar` which behaves identically without explicitly returning `None`:

```
def foobar(arg):
  if check:
    return result
# If not check, then None will be returned
```

Still, even if Python implicitly returns `None`, there is a value in being explicit; Your code becomes easier to read and understand. This is a constant trade-off for which there is no general answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think returning `None` is a "*no go*" from a usability standpoint rather than style. As briefly mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6000435/3853826) answer, consider raising an exception instead. For example:

```
def foobar(arg):
    # connect to page by httplib
    # check for arg in a certain pattern by lxml
    if not check:
        raise ValueError("arg did not match pattern in lxml")         
    return result

try:
    result = foobar(arg)
except ValueError:
    result = None

if result is not None:
    # do stuff
else:
    # do other stuff
```

The advantage of this approach is that it makes it explicit when there is not a match. Other people using your function won't need to know that `None` is the return value they should expect when there isn't a match and they can handle the exception as they see fit.

Comment: I would say that the best API depends on what `foobar` really is. Returning empty string could be the best because that allows the function to always have the same result type and the searched string is unlikely to be found (e.g. `getAtomFeedUrlFromXhtmlDocument()`). On the other hand, if it's truly exceptional that the expected string cannot be found raising an exception is better (e.g. `getRootElementNamespace()`). For some cases returning None could be the best option but I'd personally prefer either empty string or an exception always.

Answer (score 1):

There are many styles of dealing with this, including using exceptions or just returning whatever you get, including a blank string. This is fine too:

```
def foobar(arg):
    ...
    if check:
        return result

result = foobar(arg)
if result is not None:
    # do stuff
else:
    # do other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on why it's a "no go"; I haven't heard that. If it's just bad form, omit the "return None" (the else statement) altogether, and it will return None by default. If it's considered bad to return None, return 0 or '' (empty string) or False instead, depending on the type expected by the caller.

Comment: I encountered this reading the book *Clean Code* by Robert C. Martin. He claims returning or passing `Null` is a source for Errors and `NullPointerExceptions`. And if you miss one check for `Null` the program would go spinning. I can't quote the passage here because it has too much Java code examples I had to paste with it to get the context.

Comment: That applies to languages in which you can get null pointer exceptions. In Python, `None` is actually an object, not a null value.

Comment: @kindall isn't it more or less the same thing (null vs. None)? The "null"-object will remain dormant until you try to use it as the original typed object (null_object.foo()) and then throws a NullPointerException. And you those need the "is this null" checks everywhere to make sure it's not used. If a method can return None or Type you need (in the same way) check if it's None otherways (none_object.foo()) will be called and an Excepion will be thrown.